# Umbraco contour get email from workflow

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-contour

I have a receipt page that the user is redirected to after form submisson.
On this page I show a macro that summarise the form.

The gist of the macro is pretty much like this:
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/32623-Sort-and-iterate-through-form-fields-with-Razor

I would like to tell the user "you will soon receive an email" if a workflow exists, that sends an email to the submitter, on the page.

How is this feasable?
I have searched a lot on the internets and can only see how I create my own workflow, not how I access workflows by code...

Comment: There is always a workflow.  It's ONE workflow with a few states.  Can you elaborate a little bit on what you exactly mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I posted on our.umbraco and got an answer:
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/47728-Umbraco-contour-get-email-from-workflow

For your ease of access I paste the answer here:
You'll need to make use of

Umbraco.Forms.Data.Storage.WorkflowStorage

Once you create an object of that instance you can call the method GetAllWorkFlows(Form form) or GetActiveWorkFlows(Form form, FormState state)

You'll of course need the form object

And you can get that with

Umbraco.Forms.Data.Storage.FormStorage